# Migrate data from one table into multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration

I have one table `shoutbox_messages` with `user_id` and `text`.
Now I added some new tables, `chats`, `chat_users` and `chat_messages`.

Now I want to insert the data from `chat_messages` into the new structure. I created an entry in `chat`, which needs to be referenced by the `chat_users`

```
INSERT INTO chat_users (user_id, chat_id)
  SELECT DISTINCT shoutbox_messages.user_id,
    (SELECT chats.id FROM chats WHERE chats.shoutbox = true)
  FROM shoutbox_messages"
```

So far so good. Now I want to add all messages from `shoutbox_messages` to `chat_messages`

```
INSERT INTO chat_messages (chat_user_id, text, text_as_html)
  SELECT chat_users.id,
    (Select shoutbox_messages.text, shoutbox_messages.text_as_html
      FROM shoutbox_messages Where shoutbox_messages.user_id =
        (SELECT DISTINCT chat_users.id
          WHERE chat_users.user_id = shoutbox_messages.user_id
        )
    )
  from chat_users
```

This is not working, because `shoutbox_messages` have multiple texts from one user. What do I need to change, to make this work?

Comment: First, specify your specific sql language (and add its tag, too)

Comment: Done. It is postgres. Think makes no big difference. Even pseudocode would help ;)

Comment: @Sardoan the comment of @GeorgeMenoutis wasn't useless at all. It helps experts on `postgresql` to find your question and also counts for the statistics. It was actually very nice of him to point it out.. think about it.

Comment: I just want the SQL, no TSQL oder PLSSQL. Ansi SQL is ok. A language independent query would be ok. Don't see the point for adding a tag for a language independent SQL query.I wanted to reach SQL developers, not only Postres specialists, because I want the language independent query ;)

Comment: You need a query with a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to insert multiple columns into one column. as well as not inserting data into the third column, which is presumably not what you want to do.

as seen here: `(Select shoutbox_messages.text, shoutbox_messages.text_as_html
      FROM shoutbox_messages Where shoutbox_messages.user_id = ...` since your inserting data into just the  **text** this query cannot work.

pgsql is interpreting the second query as data for just the `text` column

You may want to instead of doing the syntax you currently have, use sql join syntax as it would accomplish the same thing

something along the lines of

```
SELECT chat_users.id, shoutbox_messages.text, shoutbox_messages.text_as_html
  FROM chat_users
join shoutbox_messages on shoutbox_messages.id = chat_users.id
```

just make sure you rewrite my code to the actual code you need to identify each column to the other